# How to rewrite the function from pandas time to sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have function `letter['day'] = df.created_at.dt.date`, so it converts this `2021-06-03 20:10:39.936791+03` to this `2021-06-03`.
Is it possible to rewrite them with date formatting in postgresql?

Comment: You mean a cast like this? `SELECT '2021-06-03 20:10:39.936791+03'::date`

Comment: @JimJones but this returns `2021-06-03T00:00:00.000Z` not `2021-06-03`, doesn't it?

Comment: Not really, check it out ;) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e9957399360dadaad04b8584def6fd31

Comment: @JimJones oh, then thats it, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can cast the timestamp to a simple date using `CAST`:

```
SELECT CAST('2021-06-03 20:10:39.936791+03' AS date)
```

Or using `::` :

```
SELECT '2021-06-03 20:10:39.936791+03'::date
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=55a369f3625591ac67f4cf338834e5b5)

```
SELECT '2021-06-03 20:10:39.936791+03'::date,
        CAST('2021-06-03 20:10:39.936791+03' AS date);

    date    |    date    
------------+------------
 2021-06-03 | 2021-06-03
(1 Zeile)
```